# Fixed-size and zero-initialised array as a default argument in C++11

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, initializer-list, default-arguments

**Context:** I thought that the following [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), compiled with `compile: g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp`, would zero-initialise a fixed-size array `arr`:

```
void foo(int arr[4] = {0}) { }

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

However, I debugged with `gdb` and found out that `arr = 0x0` (null). I (wildly) guess this is because `int arr[4]` is very much like `int* arr` but additionally telling the compiler to only allow arrays of length 4. Hence, what actually happens is `int arr* = {0}` ie I am just using an initializer-list to zero-initialize a pointer.

I know I can circumvent this problem by reverting back to using overloads instead of default arguments:

```
void foo(int arr[4]) { }

void foo() {
    int arr[4] = {0};
    foo(arr);
}
```

This does give me a zero-initialized fixed-size array in `foo`, as expected. However, I think it would be nice to merge these two overloaded functions into one by using some default argument, similarly to the SSCCE.

**Question**: Is zero-initialisation of a default argument fixed-size array possible in C++11. If so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main problem you are encountering is that `void foo(int arr[4])` decays to `void foo(int* arr)`, so your function does actually accept a pointer instead of an array. The simple proof is that `foo(nullptr);` will compile without errors or warnings.

As such the declaration `void foo(int arr[4] = {0});` is actually `void foo(int* arr = {0});` which initializes the pointer to 0 (trying to change `{0}` to any other number will actually cause a compile time error).

The best alternative is most likely to use `std::array` instead, for example:

```
#include <array>

void foo(std::array<int, 4> arr = {0}) { }

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    foo();
    // call with an array
    foo({1,2,3,4});
    // providing more values will cause a compile time error
    // foo({2,3,4,5,6,7,8});
    return 0;  
}
```

Note that currently there is no convenient way to convert "raw" C-style arrays to std::array, though there is a helper function in `experimental/array` called `std::to_array` which may be merged into the standard in a future version

Comment: This answers my question. However, it should be noted that passed `std::array` does not decay into some pointer --- a copy by value is made. This might be slow for large arrays or recursive calls to foo (which is what I do in my real application). This can be solved by marking the `std::array` as const and making it a reference: `void foo(const std::array<int, 4>& arr = {0}) { }`

If using const is not an option, then you could perhaps move the `std::array` instead: `void foo(std::array<int, 4>&& arr = {0}) { }`